# How to use ngx translate in a directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ngx-translate

I have a working ngx translate in my angular project. In my normal components they have a .module.ts files that ı can put my translateModule into declerations array, but I have a directive which doesnt have a module.ts so my directive cant realize my ngx translate. so how can I fix this issue?
my versions:
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",

angular 9
ionic angular 5

in my html: `{{'weather' | translate}}` but my directive cant recognize it

my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';



import {  HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })

  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    HTTP,
    Geolocation,
    NativeStorage,
    HttpService,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

for example, one of my normal working components module with translate:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { DashboardPageRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';

import { DashboardPage } from './dashboard.page';
import { ToolbarCustomComponent } from 'src/app/directives/toolbar-custom/toolbar-custom.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    DashboardPageRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardPage, ToolbarCustomComponent]
})
export class DashboardPageModule {}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue were you able to find a solution

Comment: Yes I fixed it ı will share my solution as a new comment @iqueqiorio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I created a sharedModule.ts file here:** (you dont need to import this file to somewhere or do any extra thing, thats all)

[image]

**and codes of sharedModule.ts :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { ToolbarCustomComponent } from './directives/toolbar-custom/toolbar-custom.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule  
    ],
    declarations: [
        ToolbarCustomComponent  //your custom component
    ],
    exports: [
        ToolbarCustomComponent  //your custom component
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

in your html:

```
{{'dashboardPage.yourReservations' | translate}}
```

Comment: I have done this, I had to add the shared module to parent module, so that i can use my component otherwise I get the following error:

'app-habit-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-habit-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-habit-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. 

When I add the shared module though I still get Error: The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Comment: app-habbit-item error shows that you are not successfull to import that app-habbit-item. did you add this to the shared module imports ? be sure that this is added in your app.module: schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]. and if you get the pipe translate couldnt found, that menas you are not successfull importing the module in shared module or in the app.module.ts. Can you share your codes and directory structure so ı can say something more clear? @iqueqiorio